# Undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails is throwing me the above error, pointing to this function in one of my models:

```
def is_failed?
  self.daily_post < (Time.now.utc.in_time_zone('Europe/London').beginning_of_day - 1.day)
end
```

daily_post is a :datetime method in my table for the model. At first I thought it might be a date/datetime issue, but that didn't fix it.

```
  create_table "pledges", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "description"
t.integer  "amount"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "category_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.datetime "daily_post"
t.integer  "sponsor_id"
t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_pledges_on_category_id", using: :btree
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_pledges_on_user_id", using: :btree
end
```

Controller:

```
def checkin
@pledge = Pledge.find(params[:id])

if @pledge.is_failed?
  ## pledge is over!
  flash[:danger] = "Pledge failed!"
else
  @pledge.update(daily_post: Time.now.utc)
  flash[:success] = "Checked in!"
end

redirect_to @pledge
end
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you share your daily_post method, it's somehow returning nil. Try debugging it with pry and call self.daily_post manually on console.

Comment: I put some more detail in my post, Subhash. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The statement `self.daily_post` returns `nil` in this case, and then Ruby tries to call `<` on `nil`, which is undefined method. You have to handle the situation when `self.daily_post` is `nil`, either returning true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_failed?
   self.daily_post.nil? || 
   self.daily_post < (Time.now.utc.in_time_zone('Europe/London').beginning_of_day - 1.day)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers, I managed to make a solution.

The problem was that when a new instance of the model was being created, :daily_post wasn't being given a value. So I added this to the Pledge model:

```
  def first_checkin
    if self.daily_post == nil
      self.daily_post = self.created_at
    end
  end
```

Thanks again!